# Find: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\infty} \arctan(nx) e^{- x^n}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits

> Find:
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\infty} \arctan(nx) e^{- x^n}dx$$

Probably, no recursive form could be found, and elementary tools (integration by parts, change of variable, etc.) are not useful here. How can I find such a limit?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start by thinking about pointwise limits. For $x>0$, $\arctan(nx) \to \pi/2$. For $0<x<1$, $x^n \to 0$, while for $x>1$, $x^n \to +\infty$. Hence for $0<x<1,e^{-x^n} \to 1$ while for $x>1$, $e^{-x^n} \to 0$. So the pointwise limit is $\frac{\pi}{2} \chi_{(0,1)}$, except maybe at $0$ and $1$ which don't matter.

So we might intuitively expect the limit to be $\int_0^1 \frac{\pi}{2} dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Try to use an integral convergence theorem, such as the dominated convergence theorem, to justify this result.

Comment: I thought about convergence theorems but I only know of that related to uniform convergence, which doesn't happen here. Is it valid to separate the integral as $\int_0^1 + \int_1^{\infty}$, then apply the theorem of u.c. for each? I don't know why, but I don't feel comfortable doing that.

Comment: @BolzWeir If you get the convergence you need, then it is valid, because if two limits both exist, then the limit of the sum is the sum of the limits. But I think you will have some difficulty, because the actual pointwise limit is not continuous at $0$ and $1$. So you may need to cut out some of the line, use uniform convergence on what you didn't cut out, and then add it back in, to use an argument like that one. It seems messy.

Comment: Could you tell me a little bit about the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: @BolzWeir The dominated convergence theorem is a result from *Lebesgue* integration. It says that if $f_n \to f$ pointwise almost everywhere and there exists $g \geq 0$ such that $\int g dx < \infty$ and $|f_n(x)| \leq g(x)$ almost everywhere, then $\int f_n dx \to \int f dx$. I would argue that it is the most practical result from measure theory.

Comment: @bolzweir Following up Ian's comment, note than $\arctan(x)\le \pi/2$ and $e^{-x^n}\le 1$ for $x\in [0,1]$.  So, applying the Dominated Convergence Theorem is rather straightforward.  You can use an analogous approach for $x\in[0,\infty)$.  The trick was to see the break in pointwise convergence at $x=1$.  Make sense?

Comment: @ian Very well done! +1

Comment: @Ian the two extraordinary points doesn't matter because they have measure zero, correct?

Comment: @tired Correct.